# How do I write a menu with a switch statement while using methods to perform each task

Tags: java, methods, menu, switch-statement

This program lets a user edit their string. I have problems with each method in the menu part of the program. For some reason they light up as an error, I'm using Eclispe. The rest of the code, besides the method definitions, works perfectly. I need to somehow define each task for the menu in a new method.

Each error says the exact same thing, this:

Multiple markers at this line

Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension

Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Illegal modifier for parameter shortenSpace; only final is permitted

Syntax error on token "shortenSpace", AnnotationName expected after this 
     token

I have commented in the code where my errors appear.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 public class AuthoringAssistant {
    public static Scanner scnr;
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
   userText();
   printMenu();
 }

 /** Get user text*/
 public static void userText() {
 String userText;

 System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
 userText = scnr.nextLine();
 System.out.println("You entered: " + userText);
 return;
 }

  /** Print Menu*/
   public static void printMenu() {

     String c = "c";
     String w = "w";
     String f = "f";
     String r = "r";
     String s = "s";
     String q = "q";
     String menuChoice;
     String userText;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("MENU");
     System.out.println(c + " - Number of non-whitespace characters"); /** This option counts the number of characters minus whitespace */
     System.out.println(w + " - Number of words"); /** This option counts the number of words */
     System.out.println(f + " - Find text"); /** This option finds a user specific in word in the text */
     System.out.println(r + " - Replace all !'s"); /** This option replaces all exclamation points with a period */
     System.out.println(s + " - Shorten spaces"); /** This option removes all whitespace that is larger than one space */
     System.out.println(q + " - Quit"); /** This quits */

     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("Choose an option: ");

     menuChoice = scnr.next();

     return;



 switch (menuChoice) {

 case "c": {

 public static int getNumOfNonWSCharacters(); { /** ERROR */


  // case "c": whitespace

   String newStr = "";
   newStr = userText.trim().replaceAll(" ","");
   int lenInput = newStr.length();
   System.out.println("Number of non-whitespace characters: " + lenInput);

      return;
  }
  }
  break; 

  case "w": {

  public static int getNumOfWords(); { /** ERROR */

   // case "w": number of words

   userText = userText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
   int counter = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i <= userText.length()-1; i++) {

     if (Character.isLetter(userText.charAt(i))) {

       counter++;

       for (i = 0; i <= userText.length()-1; i++) {

         if(userText.charAt(i)==' ') 
           counter++;
         }
       }                
     }

   System.out.println("Number of words: " + counter); 

   return;
  }
   }
   break;

    case "f": {

    public static String findText(); { /** ERROR */

   // case "f": find text

    System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase to be found: ");
    String find = scnr.next();  

    int matches = 0;  
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(find, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(userText);
    while (matcher.find()) matches++;

    System.out.println("\"" + find + "\" instances: " + matches);

      return;
  }
  }
  break;

  case "r": {

   public static String replaceExclamation(); { /** ERROR */

   // case "r": replace !'s

   String userTextE = "";
   userTextE = userText.replace('!', '.');
   System.out.println("Edited text: " + userText);

      return;
   }
   }
   break;

    case "s": {  

    public static String shortenSpace() { /** ERROR */


   // case "s": shortens spaces

   String userTextE = "";
   userTextE = userText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
   System.out.println("Edited text: " + userText);

      return;
  }
   }
   break;


  case "q":

  // case "q": quits

      System.exit(0);

      break;

  return;
  }
  }
  }
```

Am I supposed to have the printMenu method not contain the rest of the methods for the menu task?

Comment: There's no such thing like "nested method declaration" in Java.

Comment: @dorukayhan I am not sure what you are talking about. I'm fairly new to programming and I a simply trying to figure out how to write this program. I know it can be done because this is a challenge I was told to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define your method inside the body of the switch case. This is because,

Your code:

```
switch (menuChoice) {

 case "c": {

 public static int getNumOfNonWSCharacters(); { /** ERROR */


  // case "c": whitespace

   String newStr = "";
   newStr = userText.trim().replaceAll(" ","");
   int lenInput = newStr.length();
   System.out.println("Number of non-whitespace characters: " + lenInput);

      return;
  }
  }
  break;
```

Has a method definition within a method, (nesting of method definitions) which is not right. (That is definition of **getNumOfNonWSCharacters()** is nested within the definition of **printMenu()** )

Here's what you should do:

- Write a different java class which has the functionalities, say
  Functionalities.
- Each method of this class should carry out one of the
  functionalities/ tasks for which you have written this program.
- Then within the switch case, you create an object of the
  Functionalities class, and **call** the corresponding method.

Also, I don't see why you are returning after : `menuChoice = scnr.next();` .

Code after the `return;` will not execute, because the control returns back to the caller of this method.

Hope this helps.